# Change language in project unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to somehow change the language of the project in unity depending on the format of the windows region?
[image]

Comment: See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemLanguage.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@1.0/manual/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to check the user's system language, then you could use `Application.systemLanguage` which returns the [SystemLanguage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemLanguage.html).

If you wish to localise your project to reflect the user's language preference, look at [Unity's localization package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@1.0/manual/index.html), which provides multiple methods of translating your in-game text.